# Waiting before user reclicks a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have two buttons one with a class of 'arrow-up' and the other one with a class of 'arrow-down'. If you click on the 'arrow-down' button, the page will scroll down to the next section, and if you click the 'arrow-up' button, it will scroll up to the previous section, all of which is made with the library 'jump.js'.

The problem is whenever the user clicks multiple times on either button, the animation breaks. What I want to do is when the user clicks a button, he should wait until the animation finishes (1 - 2 seconds), then be able to reclick it.

Here is the code, or actually the onClick event :

```
  // on click event
  const onArrowClick = direction => {
    //if user clicked on arrow up button
    if (direction === 'go-up') {
      //animation to next section
      jumpTo(images[currentIndex - 1]);
      setCurrentIndex(currentIndex - 1);
      //if user clicked on arrow down button
    } else if (direction === 'go-down') {
      //animation to next section
      jumpTo(images[currentIndex + 1]);
      setCurrentIndex(currentIndex + 1);
    }
  };
  //jump to an element
  const jumpTo = image => {
    jump(image);
  };
```

Comment: Did you think about disabling the buttons after the user clicks on either of them? You can ofcourse enable it after you do `setCurrentIndex`.

Comment: Did you try with <button disabled={something} onClick={handler}>button_name</button>?

Comment: @Avanthika Yes, but it didn't seem to work unfortunately...

Comment: @KGSSandaruwan what should you put between disabled={??} ?

Comment: A state variable (let's say loading). You can set it into true, and set back into false after two seconds or something accordingly. And refer that loading variable in JSX as I mentioned (<button disabled={loading} onClick={handler}>button_name</button>).

Comment: @KGSSandaruwan Yep that would work, thanks a lot !!

Comment: It's glad to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the solution thanks to @KGSSandaruan precious hint !
Here it is :

```
   const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  //onclick
  const onArrowClick =  direction => {
    setLoading(true);
    //if user clicked on arrow up button
    if (direction === 'go-up') {
      setTimeout(() => setLoading(false), 1000);
      //animation to next section
      if (currentIndex > 0) {
        setCurrentIndex(currentIndex - 1);
        jumpTo(images[currentIndex - 1]);
        setCurrentImage(images[currentIndex - 1]);
      } else {
        setCurrentIndex(0);
      }
      //if user clicked on arrow down button
    } else if (direction === 'go-down') {
      setTimeout(() => setLoading(false), 1000);
      //animation to next section
      if (currentIndex < 6) {
        setCurrentImage(images[currentIndex + 1]);
        jumpTo(images[currentIndex + 1]);
        setCurrentIndex(currentIndex + 1);
      } else {
        setCurrentIndex(6);
      }
    }
    getData(currentIndex + 1);
  };
....
<button disabled={loading}></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

- change the `onArrowClick` to accept both `$event` and `direction` EX:

  ```
  const onArrowClick = (event, direction) => {
  .....
  <button onClick={(e) => onArrowClick(e, 'go-up')}>GO-UP</button>
  ```
- inside `onArrowClick` [use complete callback](https://github.com/callmecavs/jump.js#callback) to enable the button

  ```
  const onArrowClick = (event, direction) => {
      event.target.disabled = true; //Disable the button

      if (direction === 'go-up') {      
          jumpTo(images[currentIndex - 1], () => {
              // this callback calls when scrolling gets completed
              event.target.disabled = false; // Enable the button once the scroll completed.
          });
          setCurrentIndex(currentIndex - 1);
      }
      ....
  }
  ```

Comment: Well theoretically, that seems logical. But, after i've tried that it just kept going when you spam the button. I appreciate the precious help though !